Данные с JS скрипта внести в нужную ячейку Excel
Недавно удалось получить скрипт на js (огромное спасибо @MaxDown) для получения нужного значения с сайта.
Каким образом можно вставить значение получаемое из этого скрипта в файл Excel в нужную ячейку?
Возможно туплю и решение банальное, но ничего так и не придумал...
Сайт: https://hashrate.no/asics/ez100pro
Получаю данные с Revenue которые в 5-10 мин обновляются.
Сам скрипт:


const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block.deviceLink');

const revenue = Array.from(blocks).reduce((acc, block) => {
  const tokenElement = block.querySelector('.deviceHeader2 span[style*="font-size: 14px;"]');
  const token = tokenElement ? tokenElement.textContent.trim() : null;

  const revenueRow = Array.from(block.querySelectorAll('td')).find(td => td.textContent.trim() === 'Revenue');
  const revenueAmount = revenueRow 
    ? revenueRow.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent.trim() 
    : null;

  if (token && revenueAmount) {
    acc[token] = revenueAmount;
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(revenue);
console.log(revenue['ETC']);



PS: Будет около похожих JS скриптов, каждый на своё значение, соответственно.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.
